# Node.js hippie API testing module install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to install hippie api testing module. However, I keep getting an error when I try to run a simple script with hippie.

I did: npm install hippie

And created a file called: search.js

The code inside search.js is as simple as this:

```
var api = require('hippie');
hippie()
.json()
.get('https://api.github.com/users/vesln')
.expectStatus(200)
.end(function(err, res, body) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

And I run: node search.js

It keeps getting me an error says

```
ReferenceError: hippie is not defined
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You saved the reference to the `hippie` module in variable named `api`. Either use the `api` variable or rename it.

```
var hippie = require('hippie');
hippie()
    .json()
    .get('https://api.github.com/users/vesln')
    .expectStatus(200)
    .end(function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
```

Or:

```
var api = require('hippie');
api()
    .json()
    .get('https://api.github.com/users/vesln')
    .expectStatus(200)
    .end(function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
```

Comment: It gives me -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token R

Comment: There is no uppercase "R" in my code. This error must be comming from somewhere else.

Comment: I think it conflicts with another test module, do you get an error? Or are you able to execute the test?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but your question was a primitive "I don't know   how to use JS/Node.js" so I fixed a word for you. Your code never left my browser window.
It is hard to tell what going on without any code or at least an information where the error occurs.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if I knew how to use nodejs. I am just wondering if this is happening to most of the people or it's just me as I think this should not be happening.

Comment: This confusion is caused by the `hippie` docs:

https://github.com/vesln/hippie

The example states
`var api = require('hippie');` and later it uses `hippie()` in all its examples.